# SQL Question checking nulls

Tags: sql

I'm very new to sql. I am on this project where I have to check if something is null and if it is I have to change it to zero but there are many tables that I would have to do this and many columns. I was wondering if there was a way that I can check the whole table for nulls instead of checking every column of every table.

Comment: What platform ? MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ..?

Comment: Cool photo :-P To check column `a` use `a is NULL`, e.g. `update table set a = 0 where a is NULL`.

Comment: are you sure its just sql.  your not using any programming language ontop of the sql?

Comment: @ Gabby The platform im using is MS SQL server.

Comment: @owengerig yes Im using it in delphi

Comment: and is it your intent to change the null values in the database to 0 or is it to display those nulls as 0 within your delphi app?

Answer (score 2):

Michelle, no you need to check every column for `NULLS`. The bigger question is why are `NULLS` being allowed? While I'm not an advocate for never having `NULLS` in a database (I believe that they have their purpose), an excessive number of `NULL` values in a table is a good indicator that the database is not normalized properly or has other architectural issues.

Comment: i dont think they are saying there is an excessive amount, just alot of tables that they dont want to check each field individually.

Comment: Yes owen thats what I mean sorry for my lack in communication.

Comment: "normalized properly" is essentially meaningless. Suggested alternatives: "normalized" means [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) or higher, "fully normalized" means [5NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form) or higher.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude anything about normalization based on the "number of NULL values in a table" but I believe the burden of proof lies with you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You say you have to change any NULL values to 0, so perhaps the easiest way would be to use [`COALESCE(value, 0)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#COALESCE).

`COALESCE(value, value2, value3)` is a shortcut to a CASE statement like

```
CASE 
     WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN value1
     WHEN value2 IS NOT NULL THEN value2
     ...
END
```

**Edit:**
If you actually want to update all NULLS to 0 on the table, you could do the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT  'UPDATE ' 
        + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)
        + ' SET '
        + sc.name
        + ' = 0 WHERE '
        + sc.name
        + ' IS NULL'        
FROM    sys.columns sc 
        INNER JOIN sys.types st ON st.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id
WHERE   st.name IN ('bigint', 'int', 'smallint')        
        AND OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'YourTable'
```

Which will product a text string that you should be able to copy and paste and run, or run programatically in a loop.  It depends on your columns having a number data type, and could be dangerous if you have any such columns whose NULLs you actually want to stay as null.  You could take out that last part of the WHERE clause to run it for all tables, but you may want to test and validate beforehand.

I don't have a SQL Server instance at the ready to test on, so this comes with the generic "use at your own risk" disclaimer.  :-)

Comment: That won't identify *which* column is `NULL`, only if all of the columns were `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. The OP would still need to identify the `NULL` column to update to zero.

Comment: @Wil, I updated the answer to include a (bruteforce, somewhat hackish) way of updating any numeric column to 0 if it is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the platform, but in some cases you can use the system table information to get a list of all of the columns, and utilise this to generate queries to verify every column in every table.

However, that would be quite a hack. The real questions are a) why are there so many nulls ( there might be good reasons, but it does suggest that the structure is wrong, as per Wil ) and b) why is there a sudden need to change then all to zeros? Does this only apply to numeric fields? There are so many other questions that you need to ask before a clear solution becomes clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select nvl(col,'0') from table ;
```

NVL will work fine in oracle.

NVL will check if `col` is null, if it is null it will change it to zero.